# Ubuntu MATE dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-mate

How to dualboot Ubuntu **MATE**? Every video do stupid things, like a one selected the ext2 instead of the ext4, a one used the **UEFI** method to dualboot it on **Legacy** mode, so now I'am asking how. Please somebody answer me asap. :) Actually I have a **Legacy Boot**.
Trying to dualboot Ubuntu MATE 18.04 with Windows 7 by the way. (I already have 7 installed)

Comment: We havn't seen those videos ;-) Why don't you simply install it without doing weird things?

Comment: I'am trying to dual boot it, but it's hard for me as a begineer to know how. And people says to not use **install alongside with windows7/10 ect**.

Comment: Don't listen to "people". Go ahead and install.

Comment: Okay, but i'am gonna do it firstly on a virtual machine, is this method works for Legacy boot?

Comment: Virtual Machine is not a real install. It doesn't matter at all what is the typo of boot on a host machine.

Comment: Okay. I just remembred about my other pc, i'am gonna try it on it. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from a LiveUSB, then start "Install Ubuntu" and follow directions.

It is as simple as that.

There will be an option to install with Windows.

Comment: I'am scared if something happen :(

Comment: Then don't install.

Comment: Backup Windows first. It is always recommended.

Comment: Alright, but how.

Comment: This is off-topic how to backup Windows here.

Comment: Okay...........